# ruby error with form builder (collection), Group expected, got String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, forms

Im new to ruby and got a problem

```
= simple_form_for @user do |f|

  .form-inputs
    = f.input :name
    = f.input :email
    = f.input :group_id, collection: Group.all.collect {|c| [c.name, c.id]}
  .form-actions
    = f.button :submit
```

The line that gives me an error message is this:

```
= f.input :group, collection: Group.all.collect {|c| [c.name, c.id]}
```

Same thing with

```
= f.input :group, collection: @groups
```

The User:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :name, :group
  belongs_to :group
```

The Group:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :name
  has_many :users
```

I was also using the gem "immigration", which created the foreign key and this migration:

```
class AddKeys < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_foreign_key "users", "groups", :name => "users_group_id_fk"
  end
end
```

I saw the warning [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) about collections and form builders.
When I use

```
= f.input :group_id, collection: @groups
```

it prompts me an error message even before loading the page (not after submitting the form)

```
undefined method `group_id'
```

any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Simple Form documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#associations), you should use `f.input :group`, and not `f.input :group_id`. The beauty is that you don't have to pass in the collection, it does it automagically:

```
f. input :group
```

This should render a select input with your groups listed.

Comment: thanks, but no, it doesn't. It gives me a textfield, not the combobox I got with the collection

Comment: Well something weird is going on with you code then, because that's how I use it and, yes it does. Since you didn't mention, I think it's worth asking: do you have a group_id column in you Users table?

Comment: Fire up the console and type `User.new.group_id`. What happens?

Answer (score 0):

Change your model from Group to XGroup or anything other than Group,  I think you're conflicting with ActiveRecord's Group